# C# JSON with Chargify API

Tags: c#, json, chargify

I am new to C# and I am trying to convert a PHP script I have that creates subscriptions in Chargify (https://docs.chargify.com/api-introduction).  Below is the code I am using.  I hardcoded the JSON string for testing purposes.  After a day of working out little kinks and errors, I finally got it to a point where I am getting a 422 error back, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing it. I have read several posts on Stack Overflow concerning JSON and C# but nothing has helped.  Hopefully, someone that has more experience can look at this and point out something I am missing.  Thank you so much in advance for any insight into this matter.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(SignupViewModel regInfo)
    {

        string user = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string password = "x";

        string jsonData = "{\"subscription\":{\"product_handle\":\"149-package\", \"coupon_code\" : \"\", \"customer_attributes\":{\"first_name\":\"Jerry\",\"last_name\":\"Jenkins\",\"email\":\"joe@example.com\"},\"credit_card_attributes\":{\"full_number\":\"1\",\"expiration_month\":\"10\",\"expiration_year\":\"2020\"}, \"components\" : [{\"component_id\" : 80012, \"enabled\" : false}, {\"component_id\" : 80014, \"enabled\" : true}]}}";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://o-asandbox.chargify.com/subscriptions.json");            
        var encodedStr = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", user, password)));            
        var authorizationKey = "Basic" + " " + encodedStr;    // Note: Basic case sensitive

        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationKey);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "Content-Type: application/json";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);

        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: please read the documentation, that said `422 Unprocessable Entity is returned when the charge could not be created` and errors details are `Memo: cannot be blank.
Amount: is not a number.
Amount: must be greater than or equal to 0.
This subscription is not eligible to accept charges.
[Gateway response if a gateway fail] ([Your original memo])`

Comment: The problem was that I didn't know how to read the body of the error message until after some more digging.  I have since grabbed that and it looks like my JSON isn't being sent along due to the error saying that product is required and also that a customer is required.  Is there anything I am doing wrong with the Stream that is keeping it from being sent along?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct for sending JSON. 
The errorcode 422 is because of unprocessable data.

Search for '422' in their docs https://docs.chargify.com/api-charges
They state that along with the errorcode there is a error-response in JSON format like:

```
{"errors":[
    "Memo: cannot be blank.",
    "Amount: is not a number."
  ]}
```

Correct the mentionend errors and you should be fine.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't know how to read the body of the error message until after some more digging.  I have since grabbed that and it looks like my JSON isn't being sent along due to the error saying that product is required and also that a customer is required.  Is there anything I am doing wrong with the Stream that is keeping it from being sent along?